# How to get from web service array dynamically (Angular 4)

Tags: arrays, angular, http, dynamic

I'm trying to get data from an array dynamically without having to right every object like this:

```
<option value="City" selected="selected">City</option>
<option data-option="USA" value="LA">{{countries.data[0].cities[0].name}}</option>
<option data-option="USA" value="CA">{{countries.data[0].cities[1].name}}</option>
```

unfortunately, i cannot post the source code here because it belongs to my company but i can describe my issue

I need to not to have to write every `city` in a new `option` element, i need the elements to be generated dynamically as long as there are still index in the array, i tried to use ngfor but i dont know the right syntax for it to generate every index in an element.

I can describe further if anything is missing or not clear, just comment.

Comment: The syntax is `*ngFor="let city of country.data[0].cities"`. For more help, post code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: and what do i have to right inside the option? i mean the text should be {{city[0]}}? or what

Comment: `{{ city.name }}`.